# SQLite select count records from 10 hours ago

Tags: sqlite, select

I have this database

```
Table [Ticks]
    Fields: 2
        [Value]: INT
        [Time]: DATETIME
    Indexes: 1
        [TicksIdx]
            [Time] 
            [Value] 
    Triggers: 0
    Table constraints: 
        Primary Key: 
            Fields: 
            On Conflict: 
        Foreign Keys: 0
        Unique constraints: 0
        Check constraints: 0
Table [Ticks] end
```

And I want to count all the records with value=-1 and Time < (Now-10 hours) from 10 hours ago until now

I have this query and always returns 0

```
select count(*) from Ticks where Value=-1 and
time>=datetime('now', '-10 hours')
```

If I change the query to this then it returns all the records

```
select count(*) from Ticks where Value=-1 and
time<datetime('now', '-10 hours')
```

and I have records with time values more recent than 10 hours

Comment: What is the format of the dates in the table?

Comment: I recommend you execute `select time, datetime('now', '-10 hours') from ticks where value=-1` and you'll probably figure it out.

Comment: @forpas datetime are added to database from C# DateTime.Now

Comment: @jeff6times7 there is a difference of 2 hours, it seems that sqlite is working with UTC time, but it still should select that records

Comment: So what format are you storing the timestamp as? Remember, sqlite doesn't have any such thing as a DATETIME type.

Comment: (if you thought it does, you really need to read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html )

Comment: @Shawn I used the SQLite Expert tool to create the database and this tool have DATETIME fields, strange

Comment: Doesn't sound like whoever wrote that program is an expert on sqlite if it does something like that. Anyways, answer the question we're asking about your format (though I can 99% for sure say it's not `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` like the `datetime()` function returns and that's why your comparison is failing)

Comment: @Shawn you are right, the year, month and day positions are different in the columns when I use this query select time, datetime('now', '-10 hours') from ticks where value=-1

Comment: @Shawn how can I parse that datetime string in the order which sqlite returns it's datetime ?

Comment: @Shawn I have opened the database with this browser https://sqlitebrowser.org/ and this is the schema
CREATE TABLE [Ticks]( [Value] INT, [Time] DATETIME)

Comment: C# presumably has an easy way to format a date as a string according to a user supplied format that you can use when inserting data, but I'm not familiar with the language. Look through the documentation?

Comment: @Shawn, no I mean how to make SQLite to read the datetime correctly from it's records?

Comment: You'd have to do something ugly with `substr()` and string concatenation, assuming every field in whatever format you're using is fixed width. Better to store your data in a suitable format to start.

Comment: @Shawn I can store it in the format used by SQLite on my locale but if the program will be used in a different locale SQLite will keep it's datetime format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanations

You issue will be due to the value stored in the time column not being in a recognised format, complicated also with not comparing like for like.

The SQLite recognised formats can be found here [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions - Time Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

For example **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** (e.g. 2018-12-09 12:40:01) is such a recognised format.

You query is (assuming 9/12/2018 12:40:01 AM from c# and the runtime is the same) saying:-

- is  **9/12/2018 12:40:01 AM** >= **2018-12-09 12:40:01**

as the values are non-numeric then a character by character comparison is undertaken so using these times 9 IS greater than 2 (of course if it were 09/12..... then IS NOT).

The correct way, to ensure like for like comparison, if the underlying data is in a recognised format, would be to ensure that both sides compare dimetime's as such really the SQL should therefore be :-

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Ticks WHERE Value=-1 AND datetime(time) >= datetime('now', '-10 hours')
```

- note datetime(time) may only be needed if the date in the time column were another recognised format than the example format.

-note you may need to incorporate localtime to adjust times e.g. `datetime(time) >= datetime('now','localtime', '-10 hours')`

- as per
- > The "localtime" modifier (12) assumes the time string to its left is
  >   in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) and adjusts the time string so
  >   that it displays localtime. If "localtime" follows a time that is not
  >   UTC, then the behavior is undefined. The "utc" modifier is the
  >   opposite of "localtime". "utc" assumes that the string to its left is
  >   in the local timezone and adjusts that string to be in UTC. If the
  >   prior string is not in localtime, then the result of "utc" is
  >   undefined.

## Fix(es)

**To fix the issue you would need to either**

- do a complex reformat of the time column, dependant upon the format of the value in the time column, for the comparison (not recommended)

  - or ensure that the value is stored in a SQlite recognised format.

If the time is the current time when the ticks row is inserted, then you could use `time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the definition for the **time** column and not supply a value for the **time** column when inserting a row.

Otherwise you should change the format of the value to a recognised format before storing the value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I have stored the time values in the SQlite recognized format and now it works! Also the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP would be interesting